# Finding HTML elements by 'id' inside a coded UI test in Visual Studio using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I have a very simple Coded UI Test in Visual Studio 13' that simply visits my web page, logs in, and then clicks on a menu item that directs it to a table. During different times, that table may be empty or may be full of data. All I want to do is simply grab the 'id' attribute of the table and make assertions about its row count. Using C#, what is the easiest way to do this? I've researched and it looks like HtmlControl(s) are a possible solution [**(like the example here)**](http://executeautomation.com/blog/how-to-identify-all-the-child-elements-within-a-page-in-coded-ui-test-cuit/) but I can't seem to get the result I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public HtmlEdit TbxUserName
    {
        get
        {
            if ((tbxUserName == null))
            {
                tbxUserName = new HtmlEdit(browser);
                tbxUserName.SearchProperties[HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id] = "UserName";
            }
            return tbxUserName;
        }
    }
```

There can by problem in webforms if you have generated ids, but it can be done with 'contains':

```
divMarketMap.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "someId", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
```